# how to get uploaded file name in django

Tags: python, django

**Problem Background**
I am new to django. I am trying to upload the file from client and save it.
For this pupose i have created below model.

```
from django.db import models
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    uploadfile = models.FileField(upload_to='toProcess/')
```

I am using this model as below to save the file.

```
newfile = UploadFile(uploadfile = request.FILES['file'])
newfile.save()
```

It is saving file. But now I want to process saved file. In django, if the file with the same name alreday exists then it is adding some unique postfix to the original file name. I am happy with this approch and do not want to write a new method to create a unique filename.

Probelm- 
How to get the new unique name calculated by django for a file?

Mean If I will upload a same file two times say "abc.pdf" then it will save the first uploaded file as "abc.pdf" and second uploaded file as "abc_somesuffix.pdf". How to know what is the name of saved file?

Comment: doesn't `newfile.uploadfile.name` work?

Comment: @Pynchia- yes. it works.. thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, the filename is stored in the `name` attribute of the model field, in your case

```
newfile.uploadfile.name
```

and the path of the file is stored in

```
newfile.uploadfile.path
```

Please see the [official Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) docs for further reference, as well as many other SO Q&A (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294888/update-filefield-filename-after-uploaded-file-saved-django))

In case you want to adopt your own format for the file name you can specify a callable in the `upload_to` parameter of the model field, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime)