# Django: Display File Name for Uploaded File

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

In my model, I have a defined a `FileField` which my template displays it as a link. My problem is that the linked file displays the url as the name. What shows on html page is:

**Uploaded File: ./picture.jpg**

I've looked on the [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/) regarding file names and a previous S.O. [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574982/how-to-get-uploaded-file-name-in-django), but just can't figure it out.

How can I:

1. Have it display a different name, not a url.
2. Allow the admin who uploaded the file to give it a name, which would then be viewed on the template.

my models.py:

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    attachment = models.FileField()
```

my views.py (if entry exists, display it, if not, return message):

```
from django.core.files import File
from vendor_db.models import model_name

def webpage(request, id):
    try:
        variable = model_name.objects.get(id=id)
    except model_name.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('This item does not exist')
    return render(request, 'page.html', {
        'variable': variable,
    })
```

my page.html:

```
<p>Uploaded File: <a href="{{ variable.attachment.url }}">{{ variable.attachment }}</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your code:

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    attachment = models.FileField()
```

`attachment` is a `FileField` object, that has a property called `filename`, so just ask for that property. i.e.

```
foo = model_name.objects.create(attachment=some_file)
foo.attachment.filename # filename as a string is returned
```

Comment: This has helped, but still having some trouble. I understand that I need to call the filename attire, but shouldn't i be calling that when define foo? Also where am I putting the second line of code? In the template?

Answer (score 1):

In page.html:

```
<p>Uploaded File: <a href="{{ model.Attachment.url }}">{{ model.Attachment }}</a></p>
```

should be changed to:

```
<p>Uploaded File: {{ variable }}</p>
```

Comment: You are right, I should be displaying just the variable, however, what I am defining that variable to be is the current issue that I am having right now. I wish i could up vote, but i don't have enough rep yet lol

Answer (score 0):

To solve, I simply added an additional field to the `models.py`. This allows user to give it a name. and when displaying it on a page, call the Attachment and Attachment_Name as shown below. Hope this helps. No URL mess.

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    Attachment = models.FileField()
    Attachment_Name = models.CharField()
```

and in my html file:

```
<p>Uploaded File: <a href="{{ variable.Attachment.url }}">{{variable.Attachment_Name }}</a></p>
```