# Django: How can I display the original filename of an Uploaded file in HTML?

Tags: python, django

I want to show the exact filename of a user-uploaded file in a page, but I haven't found a sort of out-of-the-box way to do it, and I'd like to know if it exists or what could be a better way to do it.

**1.-** I can't split a string with Django's template language. I found there is a `truncatechars` filter, but that won't work for me because filenames have different lengths and, if they get truncated, I get an ellipsis at the end.

**2.-** In the only answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205155/django-display-file-name-for-uploaded-file), the user says `FileField` objects have a `filename` attribute. However, there is no `filename` attribute defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/file/#the-file-class) and, actually, if I do the same `ModelObject.field_name.filename`, I get `AttributeError: 'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'filename'`.

**Possible solutions I have found:**

- I see I can define a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) that can do `string.split('/')[-1]`, but I'm not sure if that's kind of an overkill for this. Also, note that, if this method is used, I could end up showing the user a different filename in the case in which they uploaded a file with the same name of an existing file in their user directory inside the media directory, because Django will have renamed it. This is not what I want ideally. I can find ways to ensure the user does not do this, but I'm looking for a way that avoids it in itself.
- I have also thought about creating a new model field just to store the filename gotten from `UploadedFile.name`, but again, I'd like to know about a better way.

I think it's possible I'm missing something here, but I haven't found it.

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355888/saving-original-file-name-in-django-with-filefield)

Comment: @AkashJoshi If I understood correctly, this is basically doing something similar to the second possible solution I posted (creating a new model field) but renaming the file with `uuid`. Since I am okay not renaming the file myself, then I could just set my `original_filename` field in my `upload_to` function right when I enter it, correct?

Comment: Yes perfect, as there are multiple ways to achieve that, this is one of them :) In this, you don't need to worry about the uploaded file name and appending `uuid`,  just add a new field name and save that.