# Getting Django model name of uploaded file

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model and I want to access its name. I am using `objects.get` with `id` set to 1 because I know that there is only one file that has currently been uploaded to excel_upload class. below is how i go that path for the file.

However I a looking to try and access the name of the file. by name i mean the the string associated with the file.
I know i can go into the admin panel and just click on excel_upload -> my_excel_file and then see the name. but I am looking for a way to access it in code.

```
the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.get(id=1)
excel_file_path_from_db = the_uploaded_excel_file.my_excel_file.path
print(excel_file_path_from_db)
```

my model looks like this:

```
class excel_upload(models.Model):
    my_excel_file = models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_excel_file.name[:50]
```

When i do:

```
print(excel_upload.my_excel_file)
```

i get `<django.db.models.fields.files.FileDescriptor object at 0x7fd730faa340>`

and then when i try to access the name by doing:

```
print(excel_upload.my_excel_file.name)
```

i then get:

```
    print(excel_upload.my_excel_file.name)
AttributeError: 'FileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You can access the filename using `.name`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34575210/4151233

Comment: i got an error that says:     print(excel_upload.my_excel_file.name)
AttributeError: 'FileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Not sure what `excel_upload.my_excel_file.name` is. But you should call `.name` on a specific Model object. E.g. `the_uploaded_excel_file.my_excel_file.name`

Comment: hi @Marco i have updated the question to show you the errors that keep coming up.

Comment: You have to grab this name from an object not from the class model. So first retrieve an object `the_uploaded_excel_file = excel_upload.objects.get(id=1)` and then `print(the_uploaded_excel_file.my_excel_file.name)`. Please also read [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) in the Style Guide for Python Code.

Comment: @Marco thanks i really appreciate it :)